# Proof that multiplying any probability value ($< 1$) by itself infinitely many times is zero

Tags: limits

I am trying to establish that for any non-unity probability value, multiplying it by itself infinitely many times will tend to zero. I approached the proof by creating a constant $c > 1$ and tried to establish the following limit:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{(1 - \frac{1}{c})}^n = 0$

But it's not clear why this limit must be true. Computationally, $0.99^{\text{some large number}}$ gets closer to zero, but this is not a proof of course.

Comment: Note that the probability $p$ is fixed and $p^n$ tends to $0$ whenever $p<1$ holds.

Comment: Do you agree it decreases with $n$? Can you find a value $n$ such that $(1-1/c)^n\leq 1/1000$?

Comment: The sequence $p, p^2, \cdots$ is decreasing and bounded below by $0$.  Hence it approaches a limit, $L$.  If that limit were $>0$, then for sufficiently large $n$ we have $p^n<\frac L2$ (take $n>\ln \frac L2/\ln p$), a contradiction.

Comment: Or you logarithm $p^n$ giving $n\cdot \ln(p)$. Because of $p<1$ , $\ln(p)$ is negative, hence the logaithm of $p^n$ tends to $-\infty$ , which means that $p^n$ tends to $0$. But I think lulu's argument is far eaiser.

Comment: @lulu I am not sure I understand why it is relevant that $p^n < \frac{L}{2}$. Can you please explain how this constitutes a contradiction, if $n$ is also greater than $\frac{\log \frac{L}{2}}{\log p}$

Comment: The limit could hardly be $L$ if we can produce values $<\frac L2$.  Remember, for a decreasing bounded sequence, the limit is the greatest lower bound.  There can be no terms in the sequence below the limit.